# Post request does not execute

Tags: javascript, python

There are two similar POST requests. The first one is working okay, the second one encounters problems.

First request:

```
if(document.querySelector('li.logout')){
    document.querySelector('li.logout').onclick = function(){
        alert('ok');
        var form =  document.querySelector('main > form');
         form.method = 'post';
         form.action = '/logout';
         form.submit();
}
```

Python function

```
@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    login_status = logout_user()
    if login_status:
        trigger_logged_out()
        jsonify({'result': True})

        return redirect('/')
    return jsonify({'result': False})
```

Second request:

```
if(document.getElementById('comeback_to_personal_account')){

    document.getElementById('comeback_to_personal_account').onclick = function(){  
        var form =  document.querySelector('main > form');
        alert('ok');
        form.method = 'post';
        form.action = '/comeback_to_personal_account';
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

Python function:

```
@app.route('/comeback_to_personal_account', methods=['POST'])
def comeback_to_personal_account():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        data = get_default_user_data(current_user.get_id())
        return render_sidebar_template("personal_account.html", data=data)
```

In the second request only alert executes, but python function itself - no. I cannot understand the problem here.. 
These two cases are the sme, and why one of them does not work properly?

Comment: F12 > Network > Take a look on response

Comment: What does the Network tab of your debug console say? Has the request been sent, with the right HTTP verb and the right URL path?

Comment: Sure, everything trivial has been checked..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old but I thought maybe the reason the python code is not executed is not the function but rather the if command in the function. Maybe the value `current_user.is_authenticated` is just `falsey`. Because I can see no reason why the problem should be in the javaScript.